# Error in inserting a new data column with pd.IntervalIndex

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

**Problem statement :**
Have 2 data frames A & B .

```
A:
Timestamp    datetime64[ns, UTC]
CH_0                     float64
CH_1                     float64
CH_2                     float64

B: 
Video Start Time         datetime64[ns, UTC]
Video End Time           datetime64[ns, UTC]
Video Paused                          object
Pause Time (s)                       float64
Action                                object
```

I need to figure out what Action was performed at a certain time 
in Dataframe A , for which the information is available in B with 
the help of Video start and end time.

**Solutions tried**

This is the code i am currently trying but unable to fix.

```
idx = pd.IntervalIndex(B['Video Start Time'],
                       B['Video End Time'],
                       closed='both',
                       dtype='interval[datetime64]')

event = B.loc[idx.get_indexer(A.Timestamp), 'Action']
A['event'] = event.values
```

**Error**
This is the error i have encountered.Any suggestions is highly appreciated.

```
TypeError: type <class 'numpy.datetime64'> with value 2017-10-31T03:38:18.006921000 is not an interval
```

**Sample Datasets**

```
A: 
                         Timestamp        CH_0       CH_1       CH_2  
0 2017-10-31 03:38:18.214471+00:00 -323.590000 -59.662882  -1.197040   
1 2017-10-31 03:38:18.215471+00:00 -323.552011 -43.198672   9.800288   
2 2017-10-31 03:38:18.216471+00:00 -323.565635 -28.295482  19.331956   
3 2017-10-31 03:38:18.217471+00:00 -323.567988 -12.937613  28.548840   
4 2017-10-31 03:38:18.218471+00:00 -323.544373   3.961324  38.386562   
5 2017-10-31 03:38:18.219471+00:00 -323.579086  18.777666  46.975722   
6 2017-10-31 03:38:18.220471+00:00 -323.560907  28.281476  52.537818   
7 2017-10-31 03:38:18.221471+00:00 -323.518415  31.308331  54.244971   
8 2017-10-31 03:38:18.222471+00:00 -323.583354  27.252193  51.624331   
9 2017-10-31 03:38:18.223471+00:00 -323.607014  15.752827  44.298533   


B:
Video Start Time                   Video End Time  
0 2017-10-31 03:38:18.006921+00:00 2017-10-31 03:41:48.394944+00:00   
1 2017-10-31 03:41:48.394944+00:00 2017-10-31 03:43:35.261420+00:00   
2 2017-10-31 03:43:35.261420+00:00 2017-10-31 03:45:35.498950+00:00   

  Video Paused  Pause Time (s)            Action         
            Y       41.247365        Relaxation                      
            Y       13.392300        Play      
            N        0.000000        Work
```

Comment: Can you provide some sample data  ? maybe try to convert your datetime by using pd.to_datetime

Comment: Have included the sample data in the original data

Comment: Did you check the answer?

Comment: After the statement : event = B.loc[idx.get_indexer(A.Timestamp), 'Action'] , I get this error ...TypeError: cannot determine next label for type <class 'pandas.core.indexes.datetimes.DatetimeIndex'>

Comment: That means you have not applied the to_datetime on dataframe A. Please apply the to_datetime, on all the times in both A and B as given in the answer. FYI, when I commented the line `A['Timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(A['Timestamp'])`, I too got the same error.

Comment: What version of pandas you are using?

Comment: Pandas version : 0.22.0

Answer (score 1):

First covert the times in A and B to datetime format and then use `IntervalIndex.from_arrays` as below

```
A['Timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(A['Timestamp'])
B['Video Start Time'] = pd.to_datetime(B['Video Start Time'])
B['Video End Time'] = pd.to_datetime(B['Video End Time'])

idx = pd.IntervalIndex.from_arrays(B['Video Start Time'].values,
                   B['Video End Time'].values)
event = B.loc[idx.get_indexer(A.Timestamp), 'Action']
A['event'] = event.values
print(A)
```

Alternatively, you could try

```
event = B.iloc[idx.get_indexer(A.Timestamp)]
A['event'] = event['Action'].values
print(A)
```

Comment: get this error inspite of having A & B applied with pd.to_datetime() .... TypeError: cannot determine next label for type <class 'pandas.core.indexes.datetimes.DatetimeIndex'>